# How to expand menu or close menu or array.map()

Tags: reactjs

I want to show/hide a menu depending on expanded state property. However the this part is inside a map array loop, so once you click on the action to expand the menu for one item in the array, it expands for all items.

Wondering if there is a way to achieve this.

```
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
    
    
     const handleExpandClick = () => {
        setExpanded(!expanded);
      };
    
    return (
    {results.map((result) => (
    <Grid item key={result.owner_name} xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
    <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
    <Link  to={`/guilds/${result.owner_name}`}>
      <CardHeader 
        avatar={
          <Avatar alt={result.owner_name} src={logo( result.owner_name )} className={classes.large} />
        }
        action={
          <IconButton aria-label="settings">
            <MoreVertIcon />
          </IconButton>
        }
        title={ result.owner_name }
        subheader={ datec(result.date_check) }
      />
    </Link>
      <CardContent>

      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing>
        <IconButton
          className={clsx(classes.expand, {
            [classes.expandOpen]: expanded,
          })}
          onClick={handleExpandClick}
          aria-expanded={expanded}
          aria-label="show more"
        >
          <ExpandMoreIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </CardActions>

      <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
         Stuff
      </Collapse>
      </Card>
      </Grid>
    )
```

Comment: I don't really see where the loop is in this code. It may be helpful if you include more code.

Comment: I think You can track based on the Id. And please include some more info

Comment: I've added more of the code thanks

Comment: so I use the owner_name as the key ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a sample code base, I am not sure you are looking for a similar kind of use case. Initially, All the status will be collapsed, you can click on the display id to see the change of status.

```
export default function App() {
  const values = [{ id: 1000 }, { id: 1001 }, { id: 1003 }, { id: 1004 }];
  const [expandedId, setExpandedId] = useState();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {values.map((val) => (
        <div onClick={() => setExpandedId(expandedId !== val.id ? val.id: "" )}>
          {val.id} -- {expandedId === val.id ? "Expanded" : "Collapsed"}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-antonelli-mr7fc?file=/src/App.js:65-456

Comment: Only concern is you probably would want to have it so it also collapses when you click on an expanded element.